# UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add

Tags: java, list, exception, abstract-class

I'm having issues getting a block of code to run properly. I'm not entirely sure WHAT this code does (I'm trying to get a plugin that's out of date to work properly with our server), I just know every 20 minutes it runs and throws out an error. Here's the section of code where the issue is happening:

```
public class DynamicThread extends Thread {
private LocalShops plugin = null;


public DynamicThread(ThreadGroup tgroup, String tname, LocalShops plugin) {
    super(tgroup, tname);
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

public void run() {
    Map<ItemInfo, List<Integer>> itemStockMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<ItemInfo, List<Integer>>());
    
    //Dump all the shop stock data into the map.
    for ( Shop shop : plugin.getShopManager().getAllShops() ) {
        for ( InventoryItem item : shop.getItems() ) {
            if (itemStockMap.containsKey(item.getInfo()))
                itemStockMap.get(item.getInfo()).add(item.getStock()); //Where error happens
            else
                itemStockMap.put(item.getInfo(), Arrays.asList(item.getStock()));     
        }
    }
    for(ItemInfo item : itemStockMap.keySet()) {
        List<Integer> stockList = GenericFunctions.limitOutliers(itemStockMap.get(item));
        //remove the map before re-adding it
        if (DynamicManager.getPriceAdjMap().containsKey(item)) 
            DynamicManager.getPriceAdjMap().remove(item);
        
        //Get the overall stock change for a given item and then calculate the adjustment given the volatility
        int deltaStock = GenericFunctions.getSum(stockList) - Config.getGlobalBaseStock();
        DynamicManager.getPriceAdjMap().put(item, GenericFunctions.getAdjustment(Config.getGlobalVolatility(), deltaStock)); 
    }
    
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().callSyncMethod(plugin, plugin.getShopManager().updateSigns());
}
```

}

The error happens from line 42, which is:

```
                itemStockMap.get(item.getInfo()).add(item.getStock());
```

The error it outputs happens every 20 minutes twice with 2 seconds in between.

```
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [INFO] Launch Dynamic Thread
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [SEVERE] Exception in thread "dynamic" 
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [SEVERE] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [SEVERE] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:131)
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [SEVERE] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:91)
2012-02-16 16:53:25 [SEVERE] at       com.milkbukkit.localshops.threads.DynamicThread.run(DynamicThread.java:42)

2012-02-16 16:53:27 [INFO] Launch Dynamic Thread
2012-02-16 16:53:27 [SEVERE] Exception in thread "dynamic" 
2012-02-16 16:53:27 [SEVERE] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2012-02-16 16:53:27 [SEVERE] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:131)
2012-02-16 16:53:27 [SEVERE] at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:91)
2012-02-16 16:53:27 [SEVERE] at     com.milkbukkit.localshops.threads.DynamicThread.run(DynamicThread.java:42)
```

Comment: Have you overridden equals and hashcode on ItemInfo object, because you are doing a containsKey call on the hashmap.  (itemStockMap.containsKey(item.getInfo()))

Answer (score 242):

You're using [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) to create the lists in the `Map` here:

```
itemStockMap.put(item.getInfo(), Arrays.asList(item.getStock()));
```

This method returns a non-resizable `List` backed by the array. From that method's documentation:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.)

In order to use a resizable `List` (and actually copy the contents), use the following:

```
itemStockMap.put(
        item.getInfo(),
        new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(item.getStock()))
);
```

---

**Note:** in general, when seeing that `UnsupportedOperationException` is being thrown by `add`, etc. it's typically an indication that some code is trying to modify a non-resizable or unmodifiable collection.

For example, `Collections.emptyList` or `Collections.singletonList` (which return unmodifiable collections) may be used as optimizations but accidentally be passed into methods that try to modify them. For this reason it's good practice for methods to make defensive copies of collections before modifying them (unless of course modifying the collection is a method's intended side effect) - that way callers are free to use the most appropriate collection implementation without worrying about whether it needs to be modifiable.

Answer (score 50):

I think I've worked out your problem. `Arrays.asList(item.getStock())` returns a **fixed size list** based on the Array passed to it.

This means you cannot add more elements to it.

Instead you should do `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(item.getStock()))`.

This way you are creating a new list that you can add to.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is you are creating your lists with [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). Per the javadoc provided, the returned list is a Fixed Size, therefore add would be unsupported. Wrap the returned list in a copy constructor for arrayList and you should be set.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I had used:

```
List<File> removeFilesList= Collections.emptyList();
```

which made my File arraylist abstract. Used instead:

```
List<File> removeFilesList= new ArrayList<>();
```

And the error was fixed.

Answer (score 10):

List is Interface and you can not Add value in it until it is instance of ArrayList(interface should be implemented by some class)

For Example:

```
    List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add(new Integer(2));

    ArrayList<Integer> test2 = new ArrayList<>();
    test2.add(new Integer(2));

    List<Integer> test3 = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    test3.add(new Integer(2));
```

Here Object **test** and **test2** are perfect, because they are object of **ArrayList class** so addition is possible 
While in **test3** it is just empty list so you can not add element in it.

I was also doing the same mistake.

Here is my Suggestion Use ArrayList when you have to do operations like add or remove, Use List only for reference purpose.

```
 Map<ItemInfo, ArrayList<Integer>> itemStockMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<ItemInfo, ArrayList<Integer>>());
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the class of the list object that is returned by the `get` call.  It doesn't override the `add` methods appropriately, and your code is therefore using the placeholder method provided by `AbstractList`.

There's not much more we can say without knowing what the list class is, and (if it is custom code) seeing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

in my case,using java 17 it cuased by returning a List from the stream using toList(); then adding elements to it

```
private static List<String> getCancelTxs(List<BetTransaction> betTransactions) {
        return betTransactions.stream()
                .filter(betTx -> betTx.getType().equals(BetTransactionType.SOME_THING))
                .map(BetTransaction::getExternalTxId)
                .toList();
    }
```

then adding to it by:

```
List<String> cancelTxs = getCancelTxs(betTransactions);
cancelTxs.add(externalTxId);
```

I replaced `toList();` with `.collect(Collectors.toList());`
and it resolved

Answer (score -1):

I was using a getter to get the list, but it was returning the fixed size of the list and you can't add a new element so,

Instead you should do

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(item.getStock()))
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320549/2227743).