# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException but no Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist

Getting the below exception which usually comes when we assign a list from a array using Arrays.asList() but i could not see any usage of Arrays in the code where it is being thrown. Moreover the list is initialized using new ArrayList();

```
    protected List getUnmapParam(PPlan pPlan){
        List unmappedParams = super.getUnmapParam(pPlan, ord);
            PricePlanExt apPP = null;

            if (pricePlan.getapID() != null) {
              apPP = getCurrentlyItem(pPlan.getID(), errorCodeH);
            }
            if (apPP != null) {
              List billParams = apPP.getBillParams();
              for (BillParam billParam : billParams) {
                if (billParam.getnameVal().equals("SD")) {
                  BillUnmapParamType unmappedParamType = getUnMappedType();
                  Attribute attr = mapSimpleParameter(unmappedParamType, apPP, billParam);
                  unmappedParams.add(attr);//Here it is being thrown
                }
              }
            }
            return unmappedParams;
          }

//Super method
protected List getUnmapParameters(Plan pPlan, Ord ord){
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
  }
```

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at    
 java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) at 
 java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) at 
 java.som.impl.oshooks.BillingImpl.getUnmapParam(BillingImpl.java:121)
```

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
at java.som.impl.oshooks.BillingImpl.getUnmapParam(BillingImpl.java:121)

Comment: add the stacktrace to question not in comments use edit option

Comment: Besides the actual problem: You should not put any of your classes in a package starting with `java` or `javax`. See [the documentation about naming a package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have at least one of these problems:

1. Import the wrong `ArrayList`: No `add(…)` method of `java.util.ArrayList` throws a `UnsupportedOperationException`. Looking at your stack trace indicates that the `ArrayList` you are using does not even override `AbstractList<E>.add(E)` (`java.util.ArrayList` does).
2. You are running an older version of your code: The line marked by your command (`return unmappedParams;`) would never throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`.
3. You are using a strange JRE version. If the problem is not solved by the first two suggestions, please add the exact version of your JRE (by running `java -version`).

---

After the questions edit: Now it is clear, the [answer about the list being immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30263250/1347968) is correct: You try to add something to a list returned by `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`. According to [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#EMPTY_LIST) this list is immutable.

Comment: java version is 1.7.52  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

Comment: @Sachin: What about my second guess? To be sure remove all `.class` files and rebuild your whole project. Then please also update your comment "Here it is being thrown".

Comment: I think i got it, i have actually edited the code above. There is a call to super which returns a Collections.EMPTY_LIST and when the overridden method is called, it tries to add to this list causing the UnsupportedException.

Comment: @Sachin: Just saw your update. I also added the explanation to my answer. I still don't believe the exception is thrown in the line you indicate though. ;-)

Comment: Forgot to correct the exception line. Corrected it :-)

Comment: @Sachin: Now I'm satisfied :-P

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because of `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`

In general, when seeing that UnsupportedOperationException is being thrown by add, etc. it's typically an indication that some code is trying to modify a non-resizable or unmodifiable collection.

For example, Collections.EMPTY_LIST or Collections.SINGLETON_LIST (which return unmodifiable collections) may be used as optimizations but accidentally be passed into methods that try to modify them.

See [UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320409/unsupportedoperationexception-at-java-util-abstractlist-add) for a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the root for this kind of Exception could be that the List is Immutable

See the java doc for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))