# UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add modify list inside object

Tags: java

I have got the following problem.
I want to add additional service after creating the object Product and remove it - modify the List additionalServices at CartItem class, but this exception occured.
I am working at  ShoppingCart class, which contains method void addExtraService(Product product, AdditionalService service) .

This exception occured:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

What I have written so far :

```
void addExtraService(Product product, AdditionalService service) {
    List<AdditionalService> newAdditionalServices;
    for (CartItem i : items) {
        if (i.getProduct().equals(product)) {
            newAdditionalServices= i.getProduct().getServices();
            newAdditionalServices.add(new AdditionalService(service.getName(), service.getPrice()));
            i.setAdditionalServices(newAdditionalServices);
        }
    }
}

void removeExtraService(Product product, AdditionalService service) throws Exception {
    List<AdditionalService> newAdditionalServices;
    for(CartItem i:items){
        if(i.getProduct().equals(product)){
            newAdditionalServices= i.getProduct().getServices();
            newAdditionalServices.remove(service);
            i.setAdditionalServices(newAdditionalServices);
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("Product doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

how classes look like:

```
public class Product {
    private final String productId;
    private final int price;
    private final List<AdditionalService> services;
    private final Duration expectedSendingTime;

    public Product(String productId, int price, List<AdditionalService> 
      services, Duration expectedSendingTime) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.price = price;
        this.services = services;
        this.expectedSendingTime = expectedSendingTime;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public List<AdditionalService> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public Duration getExpectedSendingTime() {
        return expectedSendingTime;
    }
}

public class CartItem {
        Product product;
        List<AdditionalService> additionalServices;
        int quantity;
        int price; 

        public CartItem(Product product, List<AdditionalService> additionalServices, int quantity, int price) {
                this.product = product;
                this.additionalServices = additionalServices;
                this.quantity = quantity;
                this.price = price;
        }

        public Product getProduct() {
                return product;
        }

        public List<AdditionalService> getAdditionalServices() {
                return additionalServices;
        }
        public void setAdditionalServices(List<AdditionalService> additionalServices) {
               this.additionalServices = additionalServices;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
                return quantity;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
                return price;
        }
}
```

Comment: show how this `List<AdditionalService> services` list was instantiated ?

Comment: nowhere yet , I had no idea if it's correct to assign it in my CartItem class, bbut I tried to assign it in Carditem and it was the same problem

Comment: What ever this statement is returning `i.getProduct().getServices();` is immutable list, which means you cannot modify that list by adding or deleting items from it, by looking at code and error message in above post i can only say this statement @Alice

Comment: If I think an simple solution, I remember the Iterator patter, you can use the iterator inside the list to remove the element from the list. should be add an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.AbstractList.add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320409/unsupportedoperationexception-at-java-util-abstractlist-add)

Comment: a little bit but still I have no idea how to get this array update it and set the new one.

Comment: @Alice, please don't insert you code in the comment, in additional, your code in the example is incomplete, and example if you call equal on the Product, you should be add the equal method inside the product. Without an example, we can not reporduce your  problem

Comment: I solved the problem by creating  `List<AdditionalItems> newArray = new ArrayList<>(here_the_old_inmutabble_array);`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whatever your underlying type for `additionalServices` is
you might not be able to modify the list.

For example:
`List<String> result = Arrays.asList("A", "B");`
Even thou your result is a list it should be clear that this list cant be modified.

Since Java has chosen to, btw. a really ugly way, declare some methods in commonly   used interfaces (List for example) even thou not all inheriting classes support that method.